# Mathematical functions Derivatives & Complex numbers in ArcMap raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

Is it possible to calculate derivatives and complex numbers on rasters inside the raster calculator in Arcmap ?

If not, is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the "Slope" of a surface which is your first derivative but I'm unsure exactly what method Arcmap uses to accomplish this.